# Creating nodes with image via REST

Tags: web-services, image, drupal, rest

I have searched all the docs but have still no clue how to create a node in Drupal 7 that contains a image field. I create the node(s) via REST Services and everything works except the image thing.

Do i have to post the image data with the post request that creates the node? (as multipart??) Or should i upload the image via ftp and link (and if, how?) to it?

maybe someone else has done a similar job.. thanks forward..

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 2.3.x you had to define a form as multipart to make file uploads work, so I think you need to create the Node as multipart aswell. Just a guess from my side, since I don't have any experience with Drupal at all.

Comment: thanks for the answer! Will look if and how multipart messages are handled by drupal..